# Logging with spring-aop

Tags: spring, logging, aop, spring-aop

I am trying to add some kind of tracing to my app. It would work like that: I set package name in my config and all calls to public methods of classes in this package are logged.

I can't use weaving here (due to some technical reasons), so I tried to use spring-proxy.
My pointcut

```
execution(public *  com.my.package.*.*(..))
```

and it works fine. But what Spring uses Proxy or CGLIB to proxy class, so each class should at least

- Have parameterless constructor
- All methods should be implementations of some interface

Other classes could not be proxied. That is ok for me to do not log them. But spring creates proxies and ruins my app.

How can I tell spring: "do not proxy this class if it has no parameterless constructor and some of its methods are not implementations of interface"?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about the answer to your question, however, another way to do the tracing, is to use an annotation:

```
public @interface Monitor {
}
```

aspect:

```
public aspect MonitoringAspect {
pointcut methodToMonitor() : execution(@Monitor * *(..));
}
```

Usage:

```
@Monitor
public void methodToBeMonitored() {
}
```

This way you only affect the methods you want to.
I suppose for a big project, this might not work as you want to monitor many methods.

Comment: Thanks, but I do not want to change my classes to add logging. I want to manage logging externally. That is what aspects for:)